# fill input text

Tags: javascript

How can I fill a text input with a value? I am trying this:

```html
<input id="curso" maxlength="150" name="curso" size="40" type="text" 
    value="window.location.href.substring(91))" />
```

But that does not work.

Comment: works http://jsfiddle.net/C2cQx/

Comment: Hi, I want to get a value from the url, when I get this value I have to put in a input text. For example if I create a button a put this onclic="window.location.href.substring(91)" I get what I want, but I need to do it in value="window.location.href.substring(91))" to fill the text of the input text

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```html
<input id="curso" maxlength="150" name="curso" size="40" type="text">

<script>
document.getElementById("curso").value =
document.getElementById("curso").defaultValue = window.location.href.substring(91);
</script>
```

You can't execute JavaScript from within an arbitrary HTML attribute.  Only `<script>` elements and event handlers can contain JavaScript, so add a `<script>` that sets the value.

You also need to set the [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#dom-input-defaultvalue) property so that any [form reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) resets the value to the desired value.